# adding images on the side using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to add two images on the side of a div how can i do this using bootstrap

```
 <div class="row">
            <asp:Image ID="guitar" runat="server" Height="187px" 
                ImageUrl="~/images/drum.jpg" Width="239px" />
            <div class="col-md-offset-5">
                     <h2>HEADING</h2>

                    <p>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttetstesttets
                        <br>ftesttetstesttetstesttets
                        <br>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttetstesttets
                        <br>testtetstesttetstesttets
                        <br>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttets.</p>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More..</a>
                    </p>

            </div>
        </div>
```

but when i insert an image this is the output  get
[image]

but i want it on the side not the top is there away i can do this using bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:Image ID="guitar" runat="server" Height="187px" 
                    ImageUrl="~/images/drum.jpg" Width="239px" />
    </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <h2>HEADING</h2>

                        <p>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttetstesttets
                            <br>ftesttetstesttetstesttets
                            <br>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttetstesttets
                            <br>testtetstesttetstesttets
                            <br>testtetstesttetstesttetstesttets.</p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">More..</a>
                        </p>

                </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4"><!-- for right hand side content--></div>
            </div>
```

This code worked for me

Comment: it seems weird that you answered your own question, isn't it ?